# Javascript comparison understanding

Tags: javascript

Why javascript return TRUE to this :

```
if (Hfin > HfinDB) {

console.log("Hfin > HfinDB =>" + Hfin +">" +HfinDB);

$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

}
```

in console log :

```
Hfin > HfinDB => 140 > 1330
```

140 is not > to 1330 and javascript return true :s

Thanks

Comment: Hm, maybe you are comparing strings? Actually, you do it, for sure...

Comment: Because strings ain't numbers. And `"1" === "1" and "4" > "3"` so the rest of the strings is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function parseInt() to convert the string into integer.

As stated in the documentation, the function parseInt will return the integer value of the left-substring obtained cutting the string where the first non numeral character is found (actually spaces are also ignored and the sign + and - are of course valid).

For example:

```
parseInt("100wrong") == 100;
parseInt("222any") == 222;
parseInt(" 100") == 100;
parseInt(" 100lll") == 100;
parseInt("-100") == -100;
parseInt("wrong222") == NaN;
```

If you parse your string variables Hfin and HfinDB, if one or both of them is "NaN", the comparison will return false;

To fix your code use:

```
var parsedHfin = parseInt(Hfin);
var parsedHfinDB = parseInt(HfinDB);
if (parsedHfin > parsedHfinDB) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: parseInt() is better or equal of number() ? have only int to convert (its only hours) so i used number()

Comment: Number() is more strict and it will return NaN if the string contains any invalid character (spaces are accepted). Number("10.30) == 10.30 and parseInt("10.30") == 10;